# Eclipse does not display /target/classes folder in "project explorer view"

Tags: eclipse

This is what it looks like in project->properties->java Build Path-> source tab . Don't know what I am missing but /target/classes folder is not showing up in "project explorer" view. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Project Explorer view defaults to not showing the output folders.

To change this click the small down arrow at the top right of the view and choose the `Customize View` option. Uncheck the 'Java output folders' option in the filters list.

Note that from Eclipse 2019-12 onwards the small down arrow is replaced by a 'hamburger' menu (three vertical dots).

Comment: this option is not available Java view . it's available JavaEE view only. I tested this in eclipse luna version

Comment: @Rams I don't use Java EE and this option is definitely there in the Project Explorer view (not the Package Explorer view)

Comment: this is Crazy..... I learned importing, packaging, maven repositories, and everything before realizing there was a difference between the real system contents and what eclipse package explorer was showing...

Answer (score 5):

[Try this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK2hl.png)
Click on Filters and customization and uncheck ***.class resources**