# Eclipse + Maven and hidden ${basedir}/target/classes folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I started to work with Eclipse and Maven. Suddenly the generated `${basedir}/target/classes` folder is not showing up in the package explorer as previously after refreshing the view. Now I am only able to see `${basedir}/target` but in the package explorer it seems to be empty even after fresh build and manual refresh. I can see the files with file explorer outside eclipse so I know they are there 100%.

How do I tell Eclipse or Maven to show the files again?

The fix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349082/eclipse-does-not-display-target-classes-folder-in-project-explorer-view) is not working for me.

Comment: I've never had a problem with the filters not working.  What version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780182/eclipse-show-generated-class-files) and notice that it is only possible in "Project Explorer" not in "Package Explorer".

Comment: I could bet I've seen it in the package explorer view. This annoys me tremendously. A tak w ogole to dzieki :D

Comment: That "notice" is what saved me from tearing out more hair.